# Implementing a download button in a filter

Tags: database, button, javafx

I am working with javaFX at a windows application, using databases.
My application is a course management system. For this thing, I made a filter for searching courses in my application. How you can see in the image above, you can select the name of teacher, the number of course, year, semester etc. All this things are extracted from my database. My problem is that i want in my filter to have a download button for each course. The idea is that i will upload courses on the internet and want for the users to download them.Could someone give me an idea about how to do? Thanks
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Well. First you need to know in which format your courses should be downloaded. What is the idea behind it - why should an user download the course? Can he import it into the calendar?

As soon as you know which format you will provide the following steps are needed:

- Add a download button to your design (probably it downloads all the courses already selected instead of adding a button per row)
- Implement an export function which exports the selected course into your prefered format
- Save the files to the disk

Edit:

Based on your comment, just some basic pseudo code. If you implemented the actual application you should be able to adapt this and write your own code for it. You will not find someone who will provide you the whole download logic and code and everything (we dont even know enough details for it), because thats not the idea. You should try it for yourself and we can help you out if you have errors or problems.

```
Button myDownloadButton = new Button();
```

Add your download action

```
myDownloadButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
    @Override public void handle(ActionEvent e) {

        // get selected row
        // create url or read url from row
        startDownload(yourUrl);
    }
});
```

Comment: The idea is that the users are students, and they will download courses for studying. I want to upload courses on the internet on sites like wetransfer. So, when a user will look for a course using filter, i want the link to appear in that list at the download, but i like to appear like a download button , not like a URL.